# How to unpin Windows 10 start menu ads with powershell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

From time to time I prepare a new PC for somebody and thought I can unpin programs and ads from menu start using powershell. It worked but only partly. I was able to unpin programs like Calendar & Weather but no idea how to get rid off windows store game ads like Asphalt 8: Airborne:

[image]

What name should i include in a script to unpin that thing (and similar)?

Here's script I use:

```
function Pin-App {    param(
        [string]$appname,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Von "Start" lösen|Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' unpinned from Start"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'An "Start" anheften|Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' pinned to Start"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
    }
}

Pin-App "Mail" -unpin
Pin-App "Store" -unpin
Pin-App "Calendar" -unpin
Pin-App "Microsoft Edge" -unpin
Pin-App "Photos" -unpin
Pin-App "Cortana" -unpin
Pin-App "Weather" -unpin
Pin-App "Phone Companion" -unpin
Pin-App "Twitter" -unpin
Pin-App "Skype Video" -unpin
Pin-App "Candy Crush Soda Saga" -unpin
Pin-App "xbox" -unpin
Pin-App "Groove music" -unpin
Pin-App "films & tv" -unpin
Pin-App "microsoft solitaire collection" -unpin
Pin-App "money" -unpin
Pin-App "get office" -unpin
Pin-App "onenote" -unpin
Pin-App "news" -unpin
Pin-App "Asphalt 8: Airborne" -unpin
Pin-App "This PC" -pin
```

Comment: So what's the output of your script for that particular entry? Did you try to have a look at the actual error? Check "Accessing The Error Record" in [PowerShell Tutorial – Try Catch Finally and error handling in PowerShell](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/e9vuP

Comment: catch `$error[0] | fl *` without `Write-Error` to see more information. now you just see your custom error message.

Comment: So I ran the script with new catch line on another user account with some crap pinned to my start menu; some of them got unpinned but got few errors like this: At line:7 char:13
+             ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: You probably did notice that you weren't able to post it. Just include it in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy a standardized start menu, you can use `Export-StartLayout` and `Import-StartLayout`:

1. Manually set up the start menu on a test machine to how you want it.
2. Export that layout to an XML file with `Export-StartLayout`.
3. Import that file on the other computers with `Import-StartLayout`.

There are more details from Microsoft here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2016/03/07/windows-10-start-layout-customization/

Comment: I successfully exported my layout however got some issues with importing it to a new machine. I tried different commands in power shell but none of them worked:
    1. Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath <path><file name>.xml –MountPath %systemdrive%

    2. Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath C:\StartLayout.xml –MountPath $env:SystemDrive

    3. Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath C:\StartLayout.xml –MountPath C:\

    First two get error: "Import-StartLayout : Could not find a part of the path"
    3rd goes without any reaction, start menu is unchanged

Comment: @Roy_Batty, it appears to set the defaults for new users, not existing users. Maybe you can just create account for the new user.

Comment: This is a "standardized menu for new users"
So it is not possible to use this for EXISTING USERS, neither is it possible to use this to fix SPECIALLIZED menues for each user. So this method is actually useless.

Answer (score 1):

This is something simple that I wrote with PowerShell to push out my custom start menu layout to Windows 10 using MDT it does start with MDT deploying the XML to the temp folder during deployment.

```
    Clear-Host

# file path that the xml must live in 
    $filepath = "C:\users\default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell"

# xml files that were copied to local machine
    $startxmlorig = "C:\Windows\Temp\startandtaskbar.xml"
    $layoutmod = "C:\Windows\Temp\LayoutModification.xml"

# test the path to see if it exists if yes then copy xmls to correct folder on if not then create the path and copy the xml files to the correct path.

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $filepath)) {
        Copy-Item -Path $startxmlorig -Destination $filepath
        Copy-Item -Path $layoutmod -Destination $filepath
        } else {
        New-Item -Force -ItemType Directory -Path $filepath
            Copy-Item -Path $startxmlorig -Destination $filepath
            Copy-Item -Path $layoutmod -Destination $filepath`
```

Comment: I left the backtick (\`) at the end of your post.   If you didn’t really mean for it to be there, [edit] it.